# Given an array and predicate, find the first matching element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there an existing function that finds the first array element that matches some general predicate?

```
$.fn.findFirstMatching = function(predicate) {
    var result;
    $.each(this, function(index, value) {
        if (predicate(index, value)) {
            result = {index: index, value: value};
        }
    });
    if (result) {
        return result;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you use [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org), then you could use [find](http://underscorejs.org/#find) method. It works even with jQuery objects storing collection of elements without problems.

```
_.find(array, function(value,index) { /* predicate */ });
```

But besides this additional (but small) library you need to write it by yourself.

Comment: Looks good. It turns out we're already using underscore, so it's even more easy. Here's the doc for anyone who's interested: http://underscorejs.org/#find

Comment: It's worth noting that it's `(value, index)`, as opposed to `jQuery.each`'s callback which takes `(index, value)`.

Answer (score 25):

As of ES2015, you can use [`Array.prototype.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

An example of using it looks like this:

```
// outputs the first odd number
console.log([2,4,10,5,7,20].find(x => x%2))
```

Comment: I like this answer the best because it does not require any third party library or framework to work.

Answer (score 17):

Another solution would be:

```
$.grep(yourArray, function (value, index) { return value == 42 } )[0]
```

Note that the order of the arguments should be `value, index`

[Docs for jQuery.grep.](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.grep/)

Of course, using **_underscore** is much more elegant and efficient (as *$.grep* applies the predicate on the all items of the array, it doesn't stop after the first match), but anyway :)

Comment: @JLRishe, the jQuery documentation states that the order should be `value, index`.

Comment: @Apelsin Indeed, you are right. Silly me, I must have assumed `$.grep` was consistent with `$.each`. Turns out they're not even slightly consistent.

Answer (score 1):

Custom implementation could be actually quite short and still readable:

```
function findFirst(array, predicate) {
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) if (predicate(array[i])) return array[i];
}
```

This returns first item matching predicate (or undefined) and then stops iteration - this could be handy for huge arrays or if predicate function is complex.

Answer (score -2):

[Use inArray method of jquery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/)

You can easily find out the index of your searched element.

Comment: The `inArray` method only takes a value, not a predicate.